# Jquery cant detect when element is empty

Tags: jquery

I face small problem when my script is telling me element is empty but in console i can see element is not empty

1st i fill up with dynamic elements

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-color', function(e){
var name = $(this).closest('.row').find('.details').data('name');

    addHtml = '<div>';
    addHtml += '<input type="checkbox" checked name="" value="'+ name +'">';
    addHtml += '<span>'+ name +'</span>';
    addHtml += '<button type="button" class="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>';
    addHtml += '</div>';

$(addHtml).appendTo('#product .selectedId div[data-name="'+name+'"]');
}
```

On remove button event

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
if ($('.selectedId:empty')) {
                console.log('empty');
            }else {
                console.log('isnt empty');
            }
```

if i add 2 elements into element "selectedId" and remove one of them i get in console "empty" but in inspector i can see there is one more element

Comment: Try `if ($('.selectedId:empty').length)`

Comment: @User863 getting "isnt empty" no matter if element "selectedId" is empty or not

Comment: Note: `:empty` also looks at text nodes (inluding whitespace used for indenting). Please add the corresponding html so we can reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if ($('.selectedId:empty'))` will always return true because :empty is a selector, and what gets returned is a jQuery array-like structure that contains the elements that matched your selector.  When converting that to a boolean, it is always true.

You probably want `if ($('.selectedId:empty').length === 0)`

Sample:

```js
$(document).on('click','#btnAdd', function(){
  $('#product').append('<p>something</p>');
});
$(document).on('click','#btnRemove',function(){
  if($('#product:empty').length > 0)
    alert('empty!')
  else
  {
    $('#product > p:first').remove();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='product'></div>
<button id='btnAdd'>Add</button>
<button id='btnRemove'>Remove</button>
```

As for empty, this is css's :empty, but for THESE tests, they are the same result:

```js
$(function(){
  $('td:empty').addClass('empty');
});
```

```css
td { outline: 1px solid red;}
td::after { content:'jquery not emtpy';background-color:orange; }
td:empty::before {
  content: 'css empty';
  background-color:red;
}
td:not(:empty)::before {
  content: 'css not empty';
  background-color:red;
}
td.empty::after {
  content:'jquery empty';
  background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span></span></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this return every time "empty" no matter if any element is in "selectedId" or not

Comment: @GameClubStreaming I've added a sample that shows how to use it.  However, be aware that if you add any text (including a space, or newline, etc) inside the #product, then it is not considered "empty".

Comment: some how white space is left in the element